# Rook on a Phone keypad - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write/come up with an algorithm for a phone keypad traversal.

Lets say I have a rook on a keypad. The rook can traverse only horizontally and vertically. My code has to input a phone number and check whether the rook is able to dial it(shouldn't go diagonal ways) and return a boolean based on the result.

[image]

Example: A phone number "4632871" is termed as "true" since the rook can traverse without going diagonally whereas "4853267" is termed as "false"

Below is my code implementation:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

function rookTraversal(arr, phoneNumber) {

  var arrIndex = [],
    numArray = [];

  var number = phoneNumber.split('')

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      arrIndex.push([i, j])
    }
  }
  arrIndex = arrIndex.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      [index + 1]: item
    }
  })
  number.forEach((item, index) => {
    numArray.push(arrIndex[item - 1])
  })

  let numArrayKeys = numArray.reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, Object.values(x).map((y, i) => y)], []);


  console.log(numArrayKeys)

}



console.log(rookTraversal(data, "4632871"))
```

I'm not sure how to proceed after this. Can someone help me out please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. You just need to pull out the x/y coordinates and check to see if one coordinate is equal to the previous. Otherwise if both aren't equal, you're going diagonal, return false.

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

function rookTraversal(arr, phoneNumber) {

  var arrIndex = [],
    numArray = []

  var number = phoneNumber.split('')

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      arrIndex.push([i, j])
    }
  }
  
  arrIndex = arrIndex.map((item, index) => ({
    [index + 1]: item
  }))
  
  number.forEach((item, index) => {
    numArray.push(arrIndex[item - 1])
  })

  let numArrayKeys = numArray.reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, Object.values(x).map((y, i) => y)], []);
  
  for (let i = 1; i < numArrayKeys.length; i++)
  {
    var x1 = numArrayKeys[i-1][0][0];
    var y1 = numArrayKeys[i-1][0][1];
    var x2 = numArrayKeys[i][0][0];
    var y2 = numArrayKeys[i][0][1];
    
    if (x1 !== x2 && y1 !== y2) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}


console.log(rookTraversal(data, "4632871"))
console.log(rookTraversal(data, "4853267"))
```